# Heroku and Sidekiq workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

Recently we implemented a few rake tasks as sidekiq workers using sidekiq-cron to schedule them.
This is a sidekiq worker metrics:
[image]

What is the most elegant way to restart the worker while it is idle?
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you could have a memory leak in one (or more) off your jobs, I would start by trying to find the jobs that are causing this problem.

Comment: @PeterZhu, I've refactored the jobs using some nice tools like 'memory_profiler' and 'Stackprof' and now to my understanding those steps are just AR  mostly. between the jobs the graph is absolutely flat so I assume this is not a leak.

Comment: That sounds like a memory leak to me. If the memory is not deallocated after jobs are completed then there is a high probability that a memory leak is going on.

Comment: @PeterZhu as you probably know ruby has a thing with deallocating memory. In anyways that is not the question ;) Thank you.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but I think you'll regret pursuing restarts instead of addressing the memory issue. Read [this page](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#memory-bloat) of the Sidekiq wiki. [These](https://www.mikeperham.com/2018/04/25/taming-rails-memory-bloat/) are some other ideas to improve memory management.

Comment: @AdamMcCrea Yeah, I agree that restarting the process is far from a great idea. We probably will keep the memory hungry tasks in a rake until a major refactoring.